# Change the client for opening a Flash project in IntelliJ

Tags: intellij-idea

Where in IntelliJ can I change the client from being opened in Adobe AIR to my regular flash player when it is done compiling? I think it is in the project settings but I cannot find *exactly* where in there.

Comment: You should improve your question title by making it more specific!

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a Flash App run configuration in:
Run > Edit Configurations > Add New > Flash App

There is a section with the option "Launch With" - choose either browser or Flash Player and run the configuration.